# Linking a formula by using a keyword

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the Mode for several columns in a sheet. If I want to find the mode in column A, I use the following formula.
=INDEX(A:2;MODE(MATCH(A:A;A:A;0)))

The data is however too large for me to individually enter each column, so I would like to know if there is a way to make the above formula dynamic in a sense that it would find the column based on the row name on the left.

So if I were to enter the formula on the cell C7(image 1), I could locate that the corresponding column on image 2 is A.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using only older functions, put this in C7 and fill down: `=Mode(Offset(Sheet2!$A:$A,0,Index(B7,Sheet2!$1:$1,0)-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,LET(a,XLOOKUP(x,D1:F1,D2:F5),b,UNIQUE(a),TAKE(SORTBY(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(c,SUM(--(a=c)))),-1),1))))
```

Comment: What do the x, a, b, and c refer to?

Comment: From left to right: 1st `MAP()` iterates all values in range `A2:A4`. So here 'x' refers to all of these values in order. Then `LET()` is a function that lets you build variables yourself. So here we created 'a' (an array through `XLOOKUP()` to return the right column from `D2:F5`), 'b' refers to all unique values from returned array in 'a'. Then in the last parameter in `LET()` we need to do our calculation with a 2nd `MAP()` to iterate these unique values from 'b' using the named variable 'c'. @Jrayman

Comment: If I were to use the formula you've given, what changes would I have to make to it to work. Now the formula has given a problem with the "c"

Comment: What would I put in for the c if I had the exact same data as you do in the picture?

Comment: I get an problem with the formula referring to the "c" when copying the data and the formula from above

Comment: After changing the c to y, I now get a NAME? error. Note that I had to change the formula's , to ; due to my excel settings, so now the formula is: =MAP(A2:A4;LAMBDA(x;LET(a;XLOOKUP(x;D1:F1;D2:F5);b;UNIQUE(a);TAKE(SORTBY(b;MAP(b;LAMBDA(y;SUM(--(a=y))));-1);1))))  might this change of , to ; have affected the formula somehow?

Comment: `NAME?` means you simply don't have one of these functions available. Make sure you update your ms365 to the current channel.